# Json object with backslash, gson serialization

Tags: json, gson

I want to convert a java object to json object with string format*. I am using gson library. Is there any way to do that.

(I am not sure if it is the correct name for this structure) json object with string format: 
*

```
{ [\"name\":\"Ajay\",\"age\":30,\"email\":\"ajay@ajay.com\"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure gson itself can't handle this, but you can. Given string `s` looking like

```
 { [\"name\":\"Ajay\",\"age\":30,\"email\":\"ajay@ajay.com\"]}
```

you only need to call gson on `s.replace("\\\"", "\"")`. Simply clean up you string, so it looks like it should (your quotation marks look differently, maybe you need to fix it, too).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing i need is to convert a Java Object into that json format.(not viceversa), because i wanna send it to an url web service, and thats the format it accepts

Comment: So do it the other way round, just switch the arguments in `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too abstruse, but if you create a JSON string (through GSON or another library like JSON.org) and GSON-serialize that string, you will get the backslashes.  This has been an irritation for me, but it would work for your case, with more code than the replace but safer if backslashes are otherwise valid in your JSON.